# Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 Linux hangs intermittently

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, motherboard

Recently I built a new system with below configuration.
1. AMD FX 8320 Octacore
2. NVIDIA Gforce GTX650
3. GIGABYTE 970A-DS3P motherboard
4. 24GB RAM
Installed latest 16.04LTS.
Unfortunately system hangs every time after few minutes of usage, some times very soon.
Suspected USB3, changed all ports to USB2, but of no use.
Followed several advices on changing bios settings, but no use.

After googling for  long time I felt that the problem is with GIGABYTE mother board. I enquired with GIGABYTE but got an answer to isntall windows.

Any one has any clue to solve the issue